# Excel How to automatically choose the whole column data?

Tags: excel

How to automatically choose the whole column data? For example the`SUM`,
When data is `A1:A20`, then the result is `=SUM(A1:A20)`, when we change data into `A1:A30`, then the result automatically become `=SUM(A1:A30)`, i.e choose the all effective data this column or `A1:End`.

Comment: Couldn't you just `=SUM($A:$A)`? I can do it but would use indirect and that's something you're better off avoiding tbh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply try using: `=SUM(A:A)`
It should ideally work.

Comment: Yes it works well, but is there any function calling for the last element of a column?

Comment: Use OFFSET maybe? Something like: `=SUM(A1: (OFFSET(A10, -1, 0)))`. A10 is the row having the **Total** value. If more rows are inserted above A10, it automatically adjusts because A10 will also shift.

Comment: I think, this is what you were looking for: `=LOOKUP(2,1 / (NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))),A:A)` This will fetch you the last value.

Comment: Yes, by the way, `LOOKUP` will automatically ignore the non-number cell?@amit.dalmia

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA, you can use the method `.End(xlDown)` with `.Select` to select the last non-empty row in a column.

`Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select`

Or instead of `.Select`, you can use `.Row` to get the last non-empty row number.

**Example code:**

```
Sub SumData() 
    Dim LastRow As Long 

    LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 
    Cells(LastRow + 2, "A").Formula = "=SUM(A1:A" & LastRow & ")" 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work to find the last row used in the range:

`MAX(IF(A:A<>"",ROW(A:A))`

To incorporate that in the SUM formula:

`=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(IF(A:A<>"",ROW(A:A)))`

**Please note that this formula will need to be entered as an array (When in the formula bar hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) and will slow down your spreadsheet if you have a lot of data in there**